# How to convert Autocad drawing to image?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I have an Autocad drawing which is a plan for land squares where each square contains a number.

I tried to convert it to image by choosing: File --> Export Data --> and file format Bitmap (bmp). (I have Autocad 2013 Mac version)

the file converted to image, but the quality is too bad, I can't see the land numbers inside the square when I zoom in the image.

I tried also with Postscript (PS file format), quality is a bit better but it's still bad.

Is there away to convert Autocad file to image but still preserve it's high quality details

I need to convert the file to image because I would like to publish it online on my website. maybe there other was to publish autocad file on line, if so, please advice. But the trick I want the background of the autcad (plan) to be transparent so that I could display it on top of Google maps. I if I used autocad plugin I can't make it transparent. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PLOT (for the current drawing) or PUBLISH (for batching) commands to produce high quality images.